# Ternary operator c#

Tags: c#

In php, I can do this:

```
$var = if($var2 == 3) ? $var : null;
```

But how can I do it in C#?

```
user_email.Content = if(dr["user_email"] == "") ? dr["user_email"] : null;
```

Does not work.

Comment: Wrong in what way? What's the error

Comment: I suspect you need to lose the if - dr["user_email"] == "") ? dr["user_email"]: null

Comment: Your PHP code is a little wrong. Even though it might have the same effect in PHP, the correct code is: `$var = ($var2 == 3) ? $var : null;`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I googled your *exact* title. First two results were documentation on ?:

Answer (score 5):

```
user_email.Content = (dr["user_email"] != null && dr["user_email"] != "") ? dr["user_email"]: null;
```

**Syntax of ?: Operator (C#):**

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. The conditional operator is of the form

Comment: I believe you want != ""  Additionally, dr sounds like it might be a DataReader, but I could be wrong. If it is, you'll need ToString() plus it might be a good idea to check against DbNull.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather rewrite it in following way

```
user_email.Content = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["user_email"]) ? dr["user_email"]: null;
```

Comment: MadMan, this will give you an error of comparing object to string. You need to do:  dr["user_email"].ToString(), +1 for IsNullOrEmpty :)

Comment: Who said that dr["user_email"] returns object ? I don't see those people ;) The questions was - "how to rewrite ?" without specifics :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the if

```
user_email.Content =  dr["user_email"] == "" ? dr["user_email"]: null;
```

You will get a warning (and possibly wrong results) :

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison,
>   cast the left hand side to type 'string'

so you may try:

```
user_email.Content =  dr["user_email"].ToString() == "" ? dr["user_email"]: null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
 user_email.Content = dr["user_email"] == "" ? dr["user_email"] : null;
```

Since setting the content to `string.Empty` if it is `string.Empty` and otherwise to `null` seems a little crazy, what I suspect what you actually mean is somthing like.

```
user_email.Content = dr["user_email"] == string.Empty ? null : dr["user_email"];
```

but, if `dr["user_email"]` could in fact already be `null` you'd be better with the following, since a null value would throw an exception in previous examples.

```
var emailValue = dr["user_email"];
user_email.Content = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailValue) ? null : emailValue;
```

using the `emailValue` variable avoids using the `dr` accessor twice.

Comment: it's called the conditional operator

Comment: I think he knows that it's called the ternary operator considering the question title...

Comment: @Erix It is actually called the ternary operator. Microsoft just doesn't know that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, the question has been edited, possibly in response to my answer.

Comment: @Jodrell Ok, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

To make it compile just remove the  `if`:

```
user_email.Content = (dr["user_email"] == "") ? dr["user_email"]: null;
```

I'd like to say that this operator is not always easy to read, especially in this case (no offence!). To make it a lot more readable I always write it in three lines:

```
user_email.Content = (dr["user_email"] == "") 
    ? dr["user_email"]
    : null;
```

But it's only a suggestion ^_^